# Singleton Instance - Performance - Why is bad code so much faster?

Tags: javascript, singleton, benchmarking, ecmascript-5

I tried different approaches with Javascript Class Construct to make singletons.

I ended up with 2 versions - Others seemed to be slower or could have problems with recursion.

**Version 1**

```
class Test {
   constructor() {
     if(Test.ins) {
        return Test.ins;
     }
     Test.ins = this;
     this.r = Math.random();
  }
}
```

**Version 2**

```
class Test4 {
   constructor() {
     Test4.ins = this;
     this.r = Math.random();
  }
  static getInstance() {
     if(Test4.ins) {
        return Test4.ins;
     }
     return new Test4();
  }
}
```

**Why I think Version 1 is bad style:**

- A constructor should never return a instance
- No one will expect a singleton instance by using new Test();
- At least in Typescript a constructor of singletons should be private!

**Why is the constructor setting singleton intance in version 2**

- First of all it was faster - Dunno why. But its faster.
- It prevents some kind of recursion if we call a function inside constructor which is trying to get the singleton instance.

So nevertheless I ended up with these 2 versions.
But now - I benchmarked them and compared together.
And I ended up, Version1 is faster by 40%. And I dont know why it is that way. If we go function step by step. Both functions are equally. If check instance and return.

This is my benchmark script: https://jsbench.me/62kg0qnila/3

Comment: "*A constructor should never return a instance*" - uh, a constructor *always* returns an instance?

Comment: @Bergi: i think OP means that constructors shouldn't use the return keyword.

Comment: thats what nathan said^^

Comment: I don't see why you care much about performance here. Your benchmark code doesn't actually do much, so no surprise that two method calls take longer than a single method call. The property lookup of the static method alone might be the difference here.

Comment: I just want to understand whats going up her. on first call, yeah there is a difference. but on continous call the ops should be exactly the same here.